# Angularjs - button on panel accordion is not registering click action for button first time

Tags: angularjs

I have a accordion panel where I have a button, when I click on button first accordion is closed and then second action on button is registered.

below is code snippet for it

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> // panel 
<div class="panel-heading" ng-model="accessInfo"
     ng-click="accessInfo=(!accessInfo)"
     style="cursor: pointer; border-top: 1px solid #37658a;">
    <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <i class="fa fa-minus" style="padding-right: 3px;" aria-hidden="true" ng-hide="accessInfo"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-plus" style="padding-right: 3px;" aria-hidden="true" ng-hide="!accessInfo"></i>
        Authorized Users
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5 pull-right" name="addUSers"  ng-show="!editEnabled" ng-click="addAuthorizedUsers($event)"
              style="margin-top: -4px;"  >
                                Add Users
             </button>
   </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define accessInfo on the scope so that it is not initially undefined.  Also `ng-model` only really applies to inputs/form elements.